# Had some issues with make command

Tags: linux, cmake, debian

could someone help with this issue?

I was following a tutorial to make my Linux Distro take a similar look to Windows 11 for experimental purposes, so I can learn something. The thing is that I experimented an issue that I searched in Google but no similar results related to my problem were found, just to let you know I'm a noob using Linux I just know the basics, I'll let you a screenshot of my terminal to let you see the error. I tried `sudo apt install KWindowShadow` and didn't work.

I'm on Debian 10 buster and unsing KDE Plasma.

```
nword@debian:~/Downloads/Lightly/build$ make
Scanning dependencies of target lightlycommon5_autogen
[  1%] Automatic MOC for target lightlycommon5
[  1%] Built target lightlycommon5_autogen
Scanning dependencies of target lightlycommon5
[  2%] Building CXX object liblightlycommon/CMakeFiles/lightlycommon5.dir/lightlycommon5_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o
[  3%] Building CXX object liblightlycommon/CMakeFiles/lightlycommon5.dir/lightlyboxshadowrenderer.cpp.o
[  5%] Linking CXX shared library ../bin/liblightlycommon5.so
[  5%] Built target lightlycommon5
Scanning dependencies of target lightlydecoration_autogen
[  6%] Automatic MOC for target lightlydecoration
[  6%] Built target lightlydecoration_autogen
[  7%] Generating ui_lightlyexceptionlistwidget.h
[  8%] Generating lightlysettings.h, lightlysettings.cpp
[ 10%] Generating ui_lightlyconfigurationui.h
[ 11%] Generating ui_lightlydetectwidget.h
[ 12%] Generating ui_lightlyexceptiondialog.h
Scanning dependencies of target lightlydecoration
[ 13%] Building CXX object kdecoration/CMakeFiles/lightlydecoration.dir/lightlydecoration_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o
[ 15%] Building CXX object kdecoration/CMakeFiles/lightlydecoration.dir/lightlybutton.cpp.o
[ 16%] Building CXX object kdecoration/CMakeFiles/lightlydecoration.dir/lightlydecoration.cpp.o
[ 17%] Building CXX object kdecoration/CMakeFiles/lightlydecoration.dir/lightlyexceptionlist.cpp.o
[ 18%] Building CXX object kdecoration/CMakeFiles/lightlydecoration.dir/lightlysettingsprovider.cpp.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object kdecoration/CMakeFiles/lightlydecoration.dir/lightlysizegrip.cpp.o
[ 21%] Building CXX object kdecoration/CMakeFiles/lightlydecoration.dir/lightlysettings.cpp.o
[ 22%] Building CXX object kdecoration/CMakeFiles/lightlydecoration.dir/config/lightlyconfigwidget.cpp.o
[ 23%] Building CXX object kdecoration/CMakeFiles/lightlydecoration.dir/config/lightlydetectwidget.cpp.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object kdecoration/CMakeFiles/lightlydecoration.dir/config/lightlyexceptiondialog.cpp.o
[ 26%] Building CXX object kdecoration/CMakeFiles/lightlydecoration.dir/config/lightlyexceptionlistwidget.cpp.o
[ 27%] Building CXX object kdecoration/CMakeFiles/lightlydecoration.dir/config/lightlyexceptionmodel.cpp.o
[ 28%] Building CXX object kdecoration/CMakeFiles/lightlydecoration.dir/config/lightlyitemmodel.cpp.o
[ 30%] Linking CXX shared module ../bin/lightlydecoration.so
[ 30%] Built target lightlydecoration
Scanning dependencies of target lightly_autogen
[ 31%] Automatic MOC for target lightly
[ 31%] Built target lightly_autogen
[ 32%] Generating lightlystyleconfigdata.h, lightlystyleconfigdata.cpp
Scanning dependencies of target lightly
[ 33%] Building CXX object kstyle/CMakeFiles/lightly.dir/lightly_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o
In file included from /home/nword/Downloads/Lightly/build/kstyle/lightly_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/../../../../kstyle/lightlyhelper.h:29,
                 from /home/nword/Downloads/Lightly/build/kstyle/lightly_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/../../../../kstyle/lightlyblurhelper.h:35,
                 from /home/nword/Downloads/Lightly/build/kstyle/lightly_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/moc_lightlyblurhelper.cpp:9,
                 from /home/nword/Downloads/Lightly/build/kstyle/lightly_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp:29:
/home/nword/Downloads/Lightly/build/kstyle/lightly_autogen/EWIEGA46WW/../../../../kstyle/lightlyshadowhelper.h:26:10: fatal error: KWindowShadow: No such file or directory
 #include <KWindowShadow>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [kstyle/CMakeFiles/lightly.dir/build.make:90: kstyle/CMakeFiles/lightly.dir/lightly_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:732: kstyle/CMakeFiles/lightly.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:149: all] Error 2
```

Comment: OK, it's done. It will be better.

Comment: Not really the make command, but `fatal error: KWindowShadow: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 2):

On opensuse, it's in the kwindowsystem-devel rpm.

If you already have it installed, then you'll need to point the makefile to some branch of it.

Comment: Debian 10 : `libkf5windowsystem-dev`

Comment: But the Debian [all versions] `libkf5windowsystem-dev` is missing some headers. KWindowShadow is one line `#include "kwindowshadow.h"` about the also missing `kwindowshadow.h` ........ All this probably because the files don't work together with the other Debian "qt5 / kf5 packages". Headers → https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1bMLXAdmfJhO0qBSUlCRg3BEQw0yZ3AYs?usp=sharing